# how to detect UV radiation?

Tags: android, sensors

most android devices have different sensors, cameras and... .if you need to detect the distance of objects to the face of the device you can use proximity sensor, if you want to know how much pressure the air has got you can simply use pressure sensor and...now, I need to go further.
how to detect the UV radiation(e.g. which comes from the sun)that faces the device via the things that an android device has (camera, ambient light sensor and etc)?

Comment: I'll be stunned if this is possible without dedicated hardware for this purpose, just as I'd be stunned if an Android device could detect X-rays without dedicated hardware for this purpose.

Comment: @CommonsWare at the first look it seems to be impossible without a dedicated hardware, yes...but as i know the camera senses the UV and it translates its wavelengths to certain RGB on the screen...so it gets more reachable !

Comment: "as i know the camera senses the UV and it translates its wavelengths to certain RGB on the screen" -- got a link?

Comment: @CommonsWare e.g. http://sci-toys.com/scitoys/scitoys/light/invisible/invisible.html

Comment: I think you'd need the specs on the sensors used in specific hardware. I know you can "hack" some DSLRs by removing UV filters to photograph in UV. I'd be surprised if camera sensors were this high-spec though.

Comment: @KenWolf but phone cameras do not have this UV filter...

Comment: Indeed, which is why I think it's not possible, what you ask, in case I wasn't clear :)

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of camera sensors can see IR radiation (point it at a tv remote and press some buttons to check if yours can), but as far as I know no off the shelf sensor can detect the UV spectrum. Even DSLRs need special lenses and filters to shoot in UV light.

Your best bet would be to attach a UV sensor to an Arduino or something, and communicate with the Android device through the Arduino.

Comment: have a look at this  http://sci-toys.com/scitoys/scitoys/light/invisible/invisible.html it shows that most of cameras interpret the UV light(at least some of their wavelengths)